# How is the memory management in polymorphism?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, memory-management, polymorphism

How is something like this saved in memory(like stack, heap etc.)?

```
public class Animal {
    // Stuff
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    // Stuff
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal bello = new Dog();
    }
}
```

how is this: `Animal bello = new Dog();`  managed in *terms of memory*?
How is this saved in memory when `bello` is a reference of type `Animal` but the objects it's pointing to is of type `Dog`

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking.  The _reference_ `bello` goes on the stack, because it's local to `main`.  The `Dog` itself goes on the heap because you created it with `new`.  But this is the same for all objects and all local variables that are references to them.  The inheritance makes no difference.

Comment: @DavidWallace but won't it make any difference if the data type of the reference isn't the same like the the one of the object?

Comment: No.  The object knows its own `class`, but it doesn't know the type of the variable that references it.

Comment: @DavidWallace ah okay and there would be also be no difference for the object itsef if the reference type were also Dog?

Comment: Correct.  A `Dog` is a `Dog` regardless of what variables there are that refer to it, and whether those variables are of type `Dog`, or `Animal` or `Object`.

Comment: @DavidWallace Then for what reason do you even have to use a data type(like `Animal` here) for the reference variable, if only the data type of the object (`Dog`) for the object itself (`bello`) counts? Is this for place where the variable is saved on the stack?

Comment: Because if you just used `Object` all the time, you'd never be able to call any methods, except those defined in the `Object` class.  The compiler makes sure that you only call methods that are appropriate for the type of the variable.  So for example, suppose the `Animal` class has a method called `eat` and the `Dog` class has a method called `bark`.  Now if you declare `bello` as `Animal`, then you can write `bello.eat()` but the compiler will stop you from writing `bello.bark()`.

Comment: @DavidWallace Thank you very much for your good answers. Just to be clear so  a data type of a reference variable hasn't anything to do with the place or adress in the stack but with the methods it can use? Is this concept the same in other languages like c++?

Comment: No, C++ is different.  In C++, the object itself can go on the stack.  In Java, you can only have objects on the heap.

Comment: Ah okay but the rest that I asked is true?

Comment: Sure.  Data types of reference variables are only really relevant at compile time.  Their purpose is to stop you from writing code that doesn't make sense.  Like `myCatFluffy.bark();`

Answer (score 1):

Java defines classes as reference types. The [Java specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) explain how this works:

> **4.3.1 Objects**
>  An  object  is a  class instance  or an  array.
>  The  reference  values  (often  just   references )  are  **pointers** 
>   to  these  objects,  and  a special null reference, which refers to no
>   object.

The language completely hides this implementation detail,  but a reference is a value that is passed (as parameter or as local variable on the the stack, or as object field in the heap) and that allows to find the real object in memory (in the heap).  So when you write:

```
    Animal bello = new Dog();
```

the JVM will allocate a `Dog` object in heap memory and `new` will return the reference to find it.  The assignment just copies the reference into `bello` local variable (the compiler will of course have checked that the types are compatible).

The trick then is in the object layout.To make it simple, the object keeps a track of its real class.  The compiler will produce an astute layout where the layout of a `Dog` object is a an extension to the `Animal` layout.   When you call a method, the method corresponding to the real object's class will then be called. Of course, in reality, all this is [a little more complex](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/dangerous-code-how-to-be-unsafe-with-java-classes-objects-in-memory/4/).

Comment: Just a pedantic nitpick: "the JVM will allocate a Dog object in heap memory" -- this is not necessarily true.  The JVM is able to allocate the Dog object on the stack if it is able to determine via static analysis that it doesn't escape the current stack frame.  See [this article by Java developer Brian Goetz for more details](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp09275/index.html).

Comment: @PeriataBreatta Very interesting article ! Thank you !  Although, my intend here was more to give a rule of thumb and an understanding of the general principle.

Answer (score 0):

Simply **Parent(base) class** will point to its **Child** extending it ,
and assigning its parent properties & methods implementation from the way that child implementing it

```
   //parent class
   public class Animal {
        int x = 5;
        int y = 5;
        void fun() { return "from Animal";}
    }

   //child class
    public class Dog extends Animal {
        //constructor
        Dog( ) {   x++; }

        @override
        void fun() { return "from Dog";}
    }
    
    public class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Animal bello = new Dog();

            bello.fun(); //return "from Dog"
            bello.x ; //6
            bello.y ; //5
        }
}
```

**I hope this diagram explains it well**

[image]